# Whenever I plug in my earphones, it asks if I plugged in earphones or microphones. How to automatically select earphones as option?

Tags: sound, microphone, speakers

A little window will pop-up asking if I plugged in a microphone or earphone, how do I automatically select earphones?

Comment: Do you have only the one jack on your computer that can handle either a microphone or headphones, or do you have separate jacks for those on your computer?

Comment: I have only one jack and the sign beside it is a picture of earphones and a microphone.  On windows, it defaults to earphones if I plug my earphones in.